# Python Code for Counting Items Under Specific Criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

I have the following data:

```
Switch1
int1
int2
int3
int4
Switch2
int1
int2
int3
int4
int5
int6
int7
int8
Switch3
int1
int2
int3
int4
int5
int6
int7
```

Please help with Python 3 code to count all the items under each of the Switches (Switch1, 2, 3).  I do have the list of the Switches in a separate file if that makes it easier.

Comment: If you have any control over the format of your data file it would be wise use YAML.

Comment: @RedCricket. Why?

Comment: Go learn about yaml and python that's why
`import yaml
my_dict = yaml.load(open('./datafile.yaml'))

for key, value in my_dict.items():
        print ( "%s has %s interfaces." % (key, len(my_dict[key])))`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your file content is stored in variable `s`, you can use `re.split` with a dict comprehension over an iterator to obtain the counts in a dict indexed by switch names:

```
import re
i = iter(re.split('(Switch\d+)\n', s)[1:])
print({k: len(v.splitlines()) for k, v in zip(i, i)})
```

With your sample input, this outputs:

```
{'Switch1': 4, 'Switch2': 8, 'Switch3': 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the file. Each line will either be a new switch or something to count:

```
switches = {}
latest = None
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Switch'):
            latest = line.strip()
        else:
            switches[latest] = switches.get(latest, 0) + 1
```

Alternatively, you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of `get` to ensure that the dictionary is populated properly for each new key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

switches = defaultdict(int)
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Switch'):
            latest = line.strip()
        else:
            switches[latest] += 1
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution I would do but with defaultdict int instead.

Comment: @Anton. That was done in good enough taste that I'll leave it in. Thanks.

Comment: If the data file was yaml you could simplify your script to `[ print ( "%s has %s interfaces." % (key, len(value))) for key, value in yaml.load(open('./datafile.yaml')).items() ]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the defaultdict solution.  I have just learned it but did not know how to apply it; I guess perhaps due to the non-programming background.  It will take some time to think like a programmer.  I have not seen yaml yet from my studying yet, perhaps it will come later.

Comment: @theotherswan. Your question was closed, but you can (and should) still accept an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would reach each line, and every time I come across a line that includes the string "Switch", I count the following line and all subsequent lines until I reach another line that includes "Switch", to which then you reset your item counter and repeat.